# Is $f(a)\leq (1-\delta) f(\frac{1}{\sqrt{C}}) \Rightarrow a\leq \frac{1- \epsilon}{\sqrt{C}} $ for $f(x)=\frac{1}{2} x- \frac{C}{6}x^{3}$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification, partial-differential-equations, maxima-minima

Define $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ as $f(x)=\frac{1}{2} x- \frac{C}{6}x^{3}$ (for some fix constnat $C>0$).

Note that  $f'(x)= \frac{1}{2}- \frac{C}{2}x^2$ and $f''(x)=-Cx.$ Also note  that $f'(x)>0$ iff $\frac{C}{2}x^2<\frac{1}{2}$ and hence $f$ is strictly incersing on $(0, \frac{1}{\sqrt{C}})$

Take $b=\frac{1}{\sqrt{C}}$ (so that $f'(b)=0$ and $f''(b)\neq 0$), and choose $0<a<b$
with the property that $f(a)\leq (1-\delta) f(b)$ for some fix $\delta >0$.

**My Question:** Can we expect to find  $\epsilon >0$(may be depending on $\delta$ and $C>0$) such that $a\leq  (1-\epsilon) b$?

> **Motivation:** I am trying to figure out the proof of  [Lemma 3.4 Equation 3.5, page 9-10](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0610266v1.pdf).  (Note that as per the notations the
>   I am taking, $a=\bar{y}, $ and $b=y_{C}$ and $N=3$(This $C$ is not the same as above)

Answer (score 1):

Be $\frac{a}{2}-\frac{Ca^3}{6}\leq \frac{a}{2}\leq \frac{1-\delta}{3\sqrt{C}}$.

With $1-\epsilon:=2\frac{1-\delta}{3}$ you get your inequality for $a$.

Comment: Why $\frac{a}{2} \leq \frac{1-\delta}{3\sqrt{C}}$?

Comment: :Thanks: Please would you explain the last inequality?

Comment: This is the condition for $1-\epsilon$ so that your inequality for $a$ holds. It's easier to use than $f(a)$. You have asked for the existence of $\epsilon$ and I gave you a value depending on $\delta$.

Comment: I agree that $\frac{a}{2}-\frac{Ca^3}{6}\leq  \frac{1-\delta}{3\sqrt{C}}$. But why $\frac{a}{2}\leq  \frac{1-\delta}{3\sqrt{C}}$ ?

Comment: You were looking for an $\epsilon$ so that the inequalities are right. For that a condition was necessary, e.g. $\frac{a}{2}\leq...$, that's the answer. With $1-\epsilon:=...$ the conclusion $...=>...$ holds.